# Jmeter HTTP requests hangs after a failover

Tags: jmeter

We have a scale test where we send Jmeter HTTP requests to a management IP address of the server. The server is running in  HA failover setup with one acting as a Primary and the other as a Secondary which uses a unique management IP for communication. After the failover of primary to secondary, the HTTP requests are not redirected to the secondary server. Please provide pointers if we need any settings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to provide reasonable timeout for connect/response under [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults), the settings live under "Advanced" tab:

   [image]

   if not timeout is specified JMeter will wait for the response forever (or according to underlying JVM/OS default timeouts)
2. Investigate your load balancer [sticky sessions mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494431/sticky-and-non-sticky-sessions), you might need to manually reset the session identifier in case of failure
3. Don't forget to add [DNS Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps/) to the Test Plan as it might be the case the first server IP address is being cached by JVM/OS and JMeter's virtual users don't resolve it for each request but rather use cached value pointing to the "dead" host